# how to call browser based css?

Tags: html, css

we can get the browser name from javascript but is there any way to change css accordingly.I mean some classes of css file because I dont want to link another css file ,  I want to write styles on
   `if chrome`

```
 a img
{
margin:0;
}

//if mozila

a img
{
margin:5px;
}
```

Comment: Just beware that these kind of hacks are hard to maintain as browser's rendering peculiarities change over time. I would do my best to try and avoid them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways:

Client side: you need to use Javascript to detect the browser and import the appropriate CSS style. Have a look at this article. (link no longer available)

Server side: you need to [detect](http://green-beast.com/experiments/php_browser_sniffer.php) the user agent and serve the appropriate HTML. Here's a [PHP source](http://green-beast.com/experiments/support/P_php_browser_sniffer.phps) link for this.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe something like

```
body.chrome a img
{
margin:0;
}

body.mozilla a img
{
margin:5px;
}
```

then use Javascript to set a class on the body as required.

Answer (score 3):

You can go for:

- [conditional CSS](http://www.conditional-css.com/advanced)
- [IE Conditional Comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is [conditional CSS](http://www.conditional-css.com/advanced) (or for IE, [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)).

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in the past with conditional includes. Detect the browser from its headers, then include a .css file based on the condition

Answer (score 1):

Use the URL-prefix for the Mozilla extension:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  a img {
    margin:5px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Using the url-prefix for the Mozilla extension. r.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
let userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
let b = "";
if(userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") > -1){
    b = "firefox";
}
if(userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") > -1){
    b = "chrome";
}

let styles = document.createElement('link');
styles.rel = "stylesheet";
styles.type = "text/css";
styles.media = "screen";
styles.href = "css/options." + b + ".css";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(styles);
```

Answer (score -2):

u can detect with js the browser version. And link the right css file.

For IE you can use

Sometimes I use -moz-CSS_ATTRIBUTE für Mozila, but it works not everytime.

I think JS is the best solution