# Using same CSS file for different browsers

Tags: css, inline-editing

I want to change only one property of only one ID for Chrome in my current CSS file. Is there a way I can do this within that CSS file:

```
if(browser == "Chrome"){
   #content {width:80%;}
}
```

Comment: This seems like a very unreliable way to do it. What do you _actually_ want to achieve? See [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: check this **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3387847/2065039)**. Preferably `javascript`..

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_navigator.asp take a look at this

Comment: Try using webkit extensions in css if it can be helped. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Webkit_Extensions

Comment: @Xufox I want to use the same css file for all the browsers, but just want to change 1 property for a different browser. Obviously it's not a wise choice to write a completely separate css file for the other browser just because of one change. That's why I was wondering if there is any way of specifying the browser within the CSS file. Hope that helps explaining what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @PHPDev If you actually want to change the property for all _Chrome users_ (and not for all users that have a _browser that displays something slightly differently which you want to correct_), then you can detect the browser with JavaScript and change the style property of all elements that match the selector, either via jQuery or via `document.querySelectorAll`. If you just want to _correct_ a behavior because it’s displayed incorrectly in Chrome, then there’s most likely a better solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

YEAH ITS POSSIBLE

```
   function checkBrowser() {
        var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
        // Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
        var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
        var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
        // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
        var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;              // Chrome 1+
        var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;   // At least IE6


        if (isChrome == true) {

          // DO CHANGES HERE

        }
```

or else something like this...

```
body.chrome a img
{
  margin:0;
}

body.mozilla a img
{
  margin:5px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but my question was: "Is there a way I can do this within that CSS file"

Comment: for that u have to use if function

Comment: something like this..   <!--[if IE]>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css"/>
<![endif]--> but i think for that also you have to use different css file.