# CSS - Render different font in different browser [css solution]

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to render different `font-family`s in different browsers?
For example, I want to use `font-family: 'A'` to be rendered in Chrome and `font-family: 'B'` to be rendered in Firefox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to call browser based css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387827/how-to-call-browser-based-css)

Comment: @Swellar yeah now I am reading about conditional tag, maybe you can explain to me more about it

Comment: @RémyTeats no, I want it to be different font-family, for example I want in chore to use 'arial' and in firefox or ie to use 'calibri'

Comment: Look into browser-hacks. However, I'm not sure you can target *only Firefox* and/or *only Chrome*, independent of version.

Comment: By the way, may I ask *why* you want to do this?

Comment: @domsson because my boss told me to do that haha.

He wants different font-family in different browser, font A for chrome and ie, and font B for firefox

Comment: I think it couldn't hurt to ask your boss *why* he wants that. It seems like quite an odd request.

Comment: @domsson He only told me before because it is our client request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually apply specific CSS properties on different browser:

```
// this targets Mozilla
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  h1 {
    color: red;
  }
}

// this targets Chrome, Safari AND Edge
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  h1 {
    color: green;
  }
}

// this targets IE
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active),
(-ms-high-contrast: none) {
  h1 {
    color: orange;
  }
}
```

The following HTML h1 tag will be green on Chrome and red on Mozilla.

```
<h1>Look at my color!</h1>
```

Comment: thanks, so can I use those to specify font-family too?

Comment: Will this work for all (future) versions of Firefox and Chrome? Can we be sure it won't also target future versions of other browsers?

Comment: can you show me how to achieve that for IE?
btw I test it on jsfiddle but thats not working

Comment: @2r83 yes you can apply any CSS properties inside the browser specific brackets.  I have edited my answer with the IE property.

Comment: @domsson,  not sure about that, Chrome, Safari and Edge have the same, as for Moz they have their own so that shouldn't change.

Comment: @Ivan thanks alot, thats really helpful, I will try it first

Comment: @2r83 Always happy to help!

Answer (score 4):

Keep the font class in separate CSS files and link them with the following JS code:

```
if (BrowserDetect.browser.indexOf("chrome")>-1) {

   document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" 
   href="../component/chromeCSSStyles.css" />');

} else if (BrowserDetect.browser.indexOf("mozilla")>-1) {

   document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" 
   href="../component/mozillaStyles.css" />');

} else if (BrowserDetect.browser.indexOf("explorer")>-1) {

   document.write('<'+'link rel="stylesheet" 
   href="../component/explorerStyles.css" />');

}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but can you tell me how it can be achieved using css only

Comment: @domsson thanks for the suggestion, I will do that next time