# Same CSS about font in different browser preforms different

Tags: html, css, font-style

When I tried to set font style on a label, the code worked perfectly on Edge, but the font was much smaller on Chrome.

This is the code:

```css
.block-footer-text{
  letter-spacing: -0.5px;
  font-size:10px;
}
```

```html
<p class = "block-footer-text">
  the text
</p>
```

I tried to add `font-size` and `font-family`, but it did not work. I also searched and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45480425/css-render-different-font-in-different-browser-css-solution) on Stack Overflow. However, according to the answer, the code is targets Chrome, Safari **and** Edge, and I want to separate Chrome and Edge. I also found other posts but they need to use JavaScript.

Is there any way to perform different CSS on Edge and Chrome without using JavaScript?

Comment: I am seeing the same (small) font size on Edge and Chrome (Windows 10).

Comment: @AHaworth [Here](https://github.com/qwerty6688/CSSPerformance/blob/main/Snipaste_2023-06-16_12-05-28.png?raw=true) is the photo

Comment: And here is mine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK7nJ.png

Comment: That's interesting. What's wrong with my Edge...(Win11 114.0.1823.51 x64)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the other question you reference does have [a CSS only way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45480528/22081063) as a different answer. However, that answer doesn't specifically cover a way to differentiate Chrome vs. Edge.

[This source](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/create-browser-specific-css) shows the relatively modern way (2022) of differentiating Chrome and Edge specifically:

```
/** Microsoft Edge */
@supports (-ms-ime-align: auto) {
div {
display: block;
}

/* Other browsers... */

}
/** Chrominum */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) and (min-resolution: 0.001dpcm) {
div:not(*:root) {
display: block;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, it does not work, and it will only perform Chromium CSS, [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/qwerty6688/CSSPerformance/main/code.txt) is the example I tried.