# IE Conditional CSS not working on Internet Explorer Browser

Tags: html, css

I am trying to write separate css for internet explorer but it is not working for me here is the code that I am using.

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css" />
 <!--[if IE]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
 <![endif]-->
```

Please provide me solution for this...

Thanks!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387827/how-to-call-browser-based-css

Comment: Not working for me have a look on a code that is posted by me it shows comment in IE also...

Comment: What I did was to create a style-ie.css and put my code inside this media query : @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active). Try and tell me if it works !